# Air application with two screens with different content

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I've been asked to build a pretty simple application using Air, which runs on one PC but uses two monitors (laptop screen and second monitor / projector).

The idea is that there will be two distinct elements - a Controller window (laptop) and a Display window (second screen).  For example, a dude will press a button on the laptop window, and it'll change the Display window - or information typed in the laptop will show on the second display.  It sounds odd, but its for a game that someone wants to set up...........

I've been messing about a bit, and I've managed to default stuff to a second screen, but I'm not sure how to get it to show different content on each and how to define where the content lives.

is this possible, or is life just too short?

Comment: Just use two separate windows ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Window.html ) and force the user to choose which screen they go on.

Comment: Use [Screen.screens](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html#screens) and [Screen.mainScreen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html#mainScreen)

Comment: cheers Reboog - I was looking for something more complicated when that just wasn't what I needed  - many thanks.